# GitLab-ci MySQL service connect via jdbc

Tags: mysql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In gitlab-ci CI/CD, during my test, I created a MySQL service and I populate it.
After this first configuration step, I want to start a set of test scripts, using a JDBC connection.
I have no idea which ip address and port are used by gitlab-ci mysql services.

This is my gitlab-ci:

```
  variables:
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: ticketsDB
  services:
    - name: mysql:5.7
      alias: ticketDBalias
  script:
     - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
     - mysql --version
     - sleep 20
     - mysql --protocol=tcp -u root -h mysql -e "create database ticketOnline; use ticketOnline;"
```

And I tried with configuration jdbc below, without any result:

> url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ticketOnline?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&requireSSL=true"
>
> url="jdbc:mysql://ticketDBalias:3306/ticketOnline?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&requireSSL=true"

```
Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [db]], took 0.0 sec
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hostname `mysql`

```
url="jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/ticketOnline?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&requireSSL=true"
```

By default, services receive a network alias that is the same name as the image used for the service. In this case, `mysql`

You can also set an explicit hostname alias for the service in your configuration:

```
services:
  - name: "mysql:5.7"
    alias: "my-db-hostname"
```

In which case you would use `my-db-hostname` as the hostname in your connection string.

---

As an aside... it's *technically* possible to set the alias as `localhost`, but that would be very confusing and potentially cause issues, so best to avoid doing that!

Comment: The first approach do not works, same for the seconds with alias...

Comment: Hmm. Please update the question with any error messages you're getting @Jonio